# UITextField to iBeacon major Xcode

Tags: xcode5, unsigned, ibeacon

I have a UITextField "userId"  that has a four digit number in it i.e. 4578.

I would like to convert that into a comparable format so I could use it in an iBeacon.major value.

I have tried numerous ways my last being:

```
long long    myLongLong           = [userId.text longLongValue];
    NSNumber *anumber      = [NSNumber numberWithLongLong:myLongLong];

NSUUID * uid2 = [[NSUUID alloc] initWithUUIDString:@"INTT1345-2C29-40E0-8E1E-1D7A9E5D0964"];
    self.beaconRegion2 = [[CLBeaconRegion alloc] initWithProximityUUID:uid2
                                                                 major:anumber
                                                            identifier:@"IDENTIFIER"];
```

but none of them have worked I keep getting the following error.

```
incompatable pointer to interger conversion sending 'NSNumber *_strong' to parameter of type 'CLBeaconMajorValue' (aka'unsigned short')
```

can someone help me out with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This:

```
NSNumberFormatter * formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
userIdInt = [formatter numberFromString:self.major.text].intValue;
```

Before ARC you could also convert a text field to an integer like this:

```
int userIdInt = [userId.text intValue];
```

You should probably do some validation before putting it into a major value.  Make sure it is not > 65535 or < 0, because these values are not allowed.  Like this:

```
if (major == nil || major.intValue < 0 || major.intValue > 65535) {
    NSLog(@"major is NOT a legal value: %@", major);
}
else {
    NSLog(@"major is a legal value: %@", major);
}
```

Comment: This still gives me an error and I want to have the exact same number that is in the textFiels be the one in the major value